# Saving form data to MongoDb does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, formidable

I have a ´form´ which includes a ´file upload´ as well. Firstly I upload the file to the ´uploads folder´ in my directory then I want to save all the form data including uploaded file path to MongoDb. But I am doing something wrong, because I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'txtEmailorPhoneNumber' of undefined
>       at Object.user.saveUser (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/user.js:23:40)
>       at app.post (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/server.js:49:10)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at serveStatic (/Users/juliatrefas/Desktop/WEBSHOP-NODE/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)

Here is my server.js:

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
server = http.createServer(app)
var formidable = require('formidable');
//app.use(formidable());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
global.db = null
var sDatabasePath = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/webshop'
global.mongoId = require('mongodb').ObjectID

/**************************************************/

var user = require(path.join(__dirname + '/user.js'))

/**************************************************/

app.get('/shopaholic', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/shopaholic.html')) })

mongo.connect(sDatabasePath, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 003 -> Cannot connect to the database')
        return false
    }
    global.db = db
    console.log('OK 002 -> Connected to the database')
    return true
})


/**************************************************/

app.post('/save-user', (req, res) => {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name
        global.sImagePath = file.path
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file) {
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });
    user.saveUser(req.fields, req.files, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(jResult)
            return res.send('ERROR')
        }
        console.log(jResult)
        return res.send('OK')

    })
})

/**************************************************/

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 001 -> Cannot listen to port 3000')
        return false
    }
    console.log('OK 000 -> Server listening to port 3000')
})
```

And my user.js:

```
var user = {}

/**************************************************/

user.saveUser = (jUserData, fcallback) => {
    var jUser = { "userName": jUserData.txtEmailorPhoneNumber, "firstName": jUserData.txtName, "lastName": jUserData.txtLastName, "password": jUserData.txtPassword, "image": jUserData.global.sImagePath }
    global.db.collection('users').insertOne(jUser, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> user.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)

        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js -> saved -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        return fcallback(false, jOk)
    })
}


/**************************************************/

module.exports = user
```

Comment: `user.saveUser` seems to expect two arguments, but you're sending three. That's kinda odd. And is anything even coming in from `req.fields`? I'd be curious as to what's sending that data. You don't seem to have any express body parsers (scrap that, just saw the "formidable")

Comment: What happens if you uncomment `app.use(formidable());`?

Comment: if I uncomment `app.use(formidable());` then I get the error: `app.use() requires a middleware function`, that´s because you need to use express-formidable in that case. In that case data from req.fields comes in and I can save to MongoDb but the file upload won´t work so I can´t save the file path to MongoDb. I am confused.

Comment: Gotcha. I did think that req.fields was empty because of not having express-formidable. Can't you use both? Add the middleware _and_ the IncomingForm, but just give them different variable names? Or am I missing something?